# Ltac: get hypotesis' type from name

Tags: pattern-matching, coq, ltac

I am looking for a way to get an hypotesis by it's name in order to match it. Like this :

```
Ltac mytactic h_name :=
let h := hyp_from_name h_name in
    match h with
    | _ /\ _ => do_something
    | _ => print_error_message
    end
.
```

Which would be used like this :

```
H0 : A /\ B
==================
A

Coq < mytactic H0.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but I'll try. You can use the `type of <term>` construction like so:

```
Ltac mytactic H :=
  match type of H with
  | _ /\ _ =>
    let H1 := fresh in
    let H2 := fresh in
    destruct H as [H1 H2]; try (inversion H1; inversion H2; subst)
  | _ => fail "Algo salió mal, mi amigo"
  end.

Example por_ejemplo x : x >= 0 /\ x <= 0 -> x = 0.
Proof.
  intros H.
  now mytactic H.
Qed.
```